# How to Scroll a bootstrap dropdown-menu programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I'm using a bootstrap dropdown-menu to show a big list of years. 
I need to scroll down the list so the `<li>` element is shown in the top.

```
<div id="year-picker" class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle left" data-toggle="dropdown"><i></i>Year</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li th:each="year : ${yearsList}"><a href="#" th:text="${year}"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the current/default behavior is that the first element appears in the top of the dropdown list, which is 2014. If I want, let's say the fifth element (2010) to be display in the top by default, how can I programmatically make the dropdown scroll until that element is in the top?

Comment: You could use ScrollTop to move (scroll) to the offset of that fifth (2010) element. That even would trigger upon opening of the dropdown, which you could listen for and detect whether it .is(':visible')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally the Bootstrap dropdown doesn't scroll so I assume you have changed the CSS to make the `.dropdown` scroll using `overflow-x` and setting a specific height.

If so, you can do something like this..

```
$('#year-picker').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  var ele = $(this).find("li>a:contains('2009')");
  var posi = ele.offset().top-ele.innerHeight();
  $('.dropdown-menu').animate({
        scrollTop: posi
    }, 1000);
})
```

http://bootply.com/130603

Comment: Definitely the answer I was looking for.

Comment: The only thing is that the offset of the element is variable and resulted in weird behavior (you can see it in your demo). But since I just need to look for the n element I'm calculating 'posi' as ele.innerHeight() * n.